# How to un-install OOB Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

When developing how do I uninstall OOB silverlight app?

In the past I've gone into  add/remove programs and found it there.

I can see there is a sllauncher.exe in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight and some params that talk about uninstall but I cannot work out to how to use the uninstall option.

Assume my app is in C:\DotNetDev2010\SilverlightBlend4\SilverlightApp\SilverlightApp
How do I uninstall it?

Thanks.

Comment: As I'm not sure what is the exact method you're looking for I'm going to say: run the application, right click over it and selected "uninstall..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated earlier, simply open the application then right-click and select Uninstall. That will work for any OOB application.

Comment: Hi, The problem is that the browser thinks the app is installed so I cannot install it. I cannot find the installed app to run it and thus cannot right click to use uninstall. :(

Comment: If I run the program in VS2010 (in browser mode) and right click the page I get the option to remove this application; but that does not work ;(

Comment: 'That will work for any OOB application.' I beg to differ :) I've got an old version of my app that now crashes on startup because configuration file is messed up. I'm not fast enough to reach the uninstall command before the uncaught exception popup comes, then the sllauncher process crash.

Comment: Another case: if you've replaced the contextual menu, you've lost that feature (sadly).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was I had set Properties\Debug\Start Action to Out-of-browser application to my site to aid debugging OOB but this sets the property App.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser in your app to true even though it is not installed.
I've set Properties\debug\Start action to Dynamically generate a test page; now it installs and uninstalls as it should.

Thanks for all your comments.